# Log in from a HTTPS submit form using CURL

Tags: php, curl

I need to submit a Login form from an external website using POST (asp.net), I was reading about this topic from here, and for several examples I couldn't make it work.

I know that I'm sending the right parameters because when using postman for testing I get the response of the Home HTML, so It must be something wrong I'm doing in code, this is what I'm trying at the moment:

```
// Create temp file to store cookies
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

// URL to login page
$url = "https://site/Login.aspx";

// Get Login page and its cookies and save cookies in the temp file
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); // Accepts all CAs
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

$fields = array(
'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtUser' => 'user',
'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtPassword' => '******',
'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'=> '716EFC3E',
'__EVENTVALIDATION'=> 'dfsgsdf5463456',
'__LASTFOCUS'=> '',
'__EVENTTARGET'=> '',
'__EVENTARGUMENT'=> '',
'__VIEWSTATE'=> 'wEPDwUKLTM1Mjk0NzM0Mw9kFgJmD2QWAgIDD2QWAgID',
'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLogin'=> 'In',
);

$fields_string = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
$fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

// Post login form and follow redirects
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); // I also try it with false
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);

echo $output;
curl_close($ch);
```

The output from this is a generic Server Runtime error.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many / most login pages use one-time-use security token values that you need to scrape from the login form.

The workflow goes like this:

1. Fetch login page
2. Scrape (parse, extract) one-time tokens from page response
3. Submit the form using the tokens

Your code looks like it is using stale hard-coded tokens.

Comment: If this is true, how come that when using postman with the same parameters actually works? that's why I'm so confuse

Comment: Your code is probably not sending exactly the same cookies and/or parameters but we'd need to see the real site to be able to tell you more.  Can you use a packet sniffer tool (on PC a good one is Fiddler2) to capture postman traffic and your php traffic?